# NUnit не прошедшие тесты падают с исключением

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Простейший тест:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SimpleTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SumOfTwoNumbers()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(2+2, 5);
    }
    }
```

нажимаю CTRL+R CTRL+A и получаю:
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException   Message=  Expected: 4
  But was:  5

Comment: а вы что ожидали? мне кажется все верно, вы получаете `AssertionException` т.к. 2+2 не эквивалентно 5. Если сделать так `Assert.AreEqual(4, 2+2);` то ошибки не будет и тест будет пройден. Кстати, там первым параметром должно быть ожидаемое значение

Comment: @tCode Я ожидал, что просто в окне test explorer будут прошедшие и не прошедшие тесты, но у меня запускается отладка и проект падает с исключением. Как-то это странно, кажется.

Comment: ну в Debug режиме это нормально, т.к. он показывает вам что и где у вас упало, запустить тесты просто как Run и увидите фейл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тестовые фреймворки в своей работе используют механизм исключений. Если вы запускаете тест с подключением отладчика и тест не проходит, то вы увидите выпавшее исключение. Если при этом продолжить исполнение и дождаться завершения теста, в списке тестов вы увидите, что этот тест красный, а текст ошибки тот же самый, что и в исключении.

В нормальной ситуации тесты запускаются без подключения отладчика, поэтому вы сразу видите в списке тестов, что они зеленые/красные.